# Override default Auth routes in Laravel >= 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to override `/login` route to `/admin/login`. In `web.php` I tried

```
//Auth::routes();
Route::get('login', ['as' => 'auth.login', 'uses' => 'App\Modules\Admin\Controllers\AdminUserController@loginAdminUser'])->name('login');
```

But it is still showing Laravel default login form. How can I do this?

Comment: Just remember that when you update your laravel application, this will all reset.

Comment: Read this guide https://medium.com/@panjeh/laravel-auth-routes-email-verification-reset-password-authentication-registration-routes-fb82b3337150

Answer (score 86, accepted):

For the googlers, here is a full list of routes that are getting generated by `Auth::routes();` in Laravel >= 5.4

```
// Authentication Routes...
Route::get('login', [
  'as' => 'login',
  'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm'
]);
Route::post('login', [
  'as' => '',
  'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@login'
]);
Route::post('logout', [
  'as' => 'logout',
  'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@logout'
]);

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::post('password/email', [
  'as' => 'password.email',
  'uses' => 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail'
]);
Route::get('password/reset', [
  'as' => 'password.request',
  'uses' => 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm'
]);
Route::post('password/reset', [
  'as' => 'password.update',
  'uses' => 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset'
]);
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', [
  'as' => 'password.reset',
  'uses' => 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm'
]);

// Registration Routes...
Route::get('register', [
  'as' => 'register',
  'uses' => 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm'
]);
Route::post('register', [
  'as' => '',
  'uses' => 'Auth\RegisterController@register'
]);
```

`php artisan route:list` will return

```
+--------+----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                    | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | login                  | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | login                  |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | logout                 | logout           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web          |
|        | POST     | password/email         | password.email   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset         | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | password/reset         | password.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token} | password.reset   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | register               | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | register               |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest    |
+--------+----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Email verification (5.6+):

     ```$this->get('email/verify', 'Auth\VerificationController@show')->name('verification.notice');

        $this->get('email/verify/{id}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');

        $this->get('email/resend', 'Auth\VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');```

Comment: In newer versions of Laravel (in my case 5.7) the routes are the same but one change was made. The password reset route `POST password/reset` got an alias `'password.update'`. I think it is not a problem to set the alias also for older version. So let's change your solution and add that alias.

Comment: @algorhythm Thanks for the hint. You're right, no one will get hurt by the alias.

Comment: 5.8.17 GET|HEAD: login, password/reset, password/reset/{token}, register POST: login, logout, password/reset, register, password/email

Answer (score 47):

You can also try this one.

```
// Replace admin with whatever prefix you need

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {

    Auth::routes();

});
```

You can see list of routes by following command.

`php artisan route:list`

[image]

Comment: I cant thank you enough, not having this caused me to have to start rewriting all the routes, not only that, but all the LoginController methods to override, and the routes renamed to avoid confusion.  I was able to remove all my custom routing with this prefix!

Comment: Perfect! Works in 5.7

Comment: Works with 5.8 :)

Comment: Thank you I have been looking for this answer for the last 2 days

Comment: Brilliant! This should be the correct answer.

Comment: This is the real answer instead that one.

Answer (score 13):

Routes for **5.5 LTS** (Confirmed) / **5.6** (Confirmed) / **5.7** (?)

Can someone confirm it works with 5.7?

```
// Authentication Routes...
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

Comment: Thanks. This Route Auth for Laravel 5.6 the same :)

Comment: Just went here to confirm that my snippet is still working in 5.6

Comment: thanks Lucas! but... where is the file so I can overwrite it?

Comment: @gtamborero those are routes, lookup for routes documentation on Laravel

Comment: Thanks Lucas. thats the directory -> vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php

Comment: As I commented at @GordonFreemans solution: "In newer versions of Laravel (in my case 5.7) the routes are the same but one change was made. The password reset route `POST password/reset` got an alias `'password.update'`. I think it is not a problem to set the alias also for older version."

Comment: 5.8.17 

GET|HEAD: login, password/reset, password/reset/{token}, register
POST: login, logout, password/reset, register, password/email

Comment: i want to set name for any of those routes that using in my Laravel project modules that in vendor folder,. how can i set name for them in my project if they upgraded i can customize them?

Answer (score 9):

As I was struggling with the same problem I managed to find a good way to *override* laravel **5.5** routes:

The static function Auth::routes(); :

```
public static function routes()
{
    static::$app->make('router')->auth();
}
```

The auth() function is called here which creates auth routes:

> laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php

```
public function auth()
{
    // Authentication Routes...
    $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
    $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    $this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    $this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

    // Password Reset Routes...
    $this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
    $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
    $this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
    $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
}
```

You can copy&paste the body of the function right into your web.php and modify them as you wish.

Answer (score 9):

You can find all the login routes of Laravel 5.7. There is something new, e-mail verification. Related documentation is [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification).

If statements in the code block basically enables/disables auth features. By using helper, you can pass `register`, `reset`, `verify` parameters to `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);`. So fix `if` statements by using `config()` or just use as you wish.

**Wrapping up here!**
When you call `Auth::routes()`, following routes will be registered.

```
Route::get('login', 'LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
if (config('register'))
{
    Route::get('register', 'RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@register');
}
// Password Reset Routes...
if (config('reset'))
{
    Route::get('password/reset', 'ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
    Route::post('password/email', 'ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
    Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
    Route::post('password/reset', 'ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.update');
}
// Email Verification Routes...
if (config('verify'))
{
    Route::get('email/verify', 'VerificationController@show')->name('verification.notice');
    Route::get('email/verify/{id}', 'VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
    Route::get('email/resend', 'VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');
}
```

Comment: how can i set name for those modules in my laravel app

Comment: basically delete `Auth::routes() ` in your route file or overwrite default Laravel auth routes in your route file. Any further help, you must to give more information about the thing you'd like to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Change this to :

```
Route::get('/admin/login', ['as' => 'admin.login', 'uses' => 'App\Modules\Admin\Controllers\AdminUserController@loginAdminUser']);

    Route::get('login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'App\Modules\Admin\Controllers\AdminUserController@loginAdminUser']);
```

`name` function is the synonyms for `as` key of array. So no need to add `name` at the end.

Comment: What will happen if user try /login?

Comment: It will throw a `NotFoundHttpException`.

Comment: But I want to override this route to '/admin/login'

Comment: If u want to use both the route you can add both the route. Check the answer.